# random forest and classification using tidymodels problem with outcome variable

Tags: r, classification, random-forest, tidymodels

I am working on a very basic version of simulating a random forest model using tidymodels and ranger.  I am just trying to make it run.  I will deal with the validity of the model later.  When I run the model, I get the following error:

"unique notes:
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Error in `check_outcome()`:
! For a classification model, the outcome should be a factor."

I am at a loss because the simulated data, clearly, has the outcome as a factor.  What am I missing? Is this a situation, where the vfolds is selecting portions of the outcome that does not have the complete factor?  How would I check this?

Here is the code I am using:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(themis)
library(dplyr)
library(vip)
library(forcats)

set.seed(987)
n = 1500

#simulated data
v1 = sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = TRUE)
v2 = round(runif(n, 18, 80))
v3 = sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = TRUE)
v4 = sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = TRUE)
v5 = sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = TRUE)
v6 = rbinom(n = n, size = 1, prob = .50)

xb = -9 + 3.5*v1 + 0.2*v2 + 0*v3 + 0*v4 +0*v5 + 0*v6  
p = 1/(1 + exp(-xb))

y1 = rbinom(n = n, size = 1, prob = p)

y1 = 
  dplyr::recode_factor(y1, `1` = "yes", `2` =  "no")

dat_set = as.data.frame(cbind(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, y1))

dat_set |> 
  count(y1)

class(y1)

#splitting into training and testing data
set.seed(123)
rf_split = initial_split(dat_set, strata = y1)
rf_train = training(rf_split)
rf_test = testing(rf_split)

#developing the model
set.seed(234)
rf_folds = vfold_cv(rf_train, strata = y1)

ranger_recipe = 
  recipe(formula = y1 ~ ., data = rf_train)

ranger_spec = 
  rand_forest(mtry = tune(), min_n = tune(), trees = 1000)  |>  
  set_mode("classification")  |>  
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity") 

ranger_workflow = 
  workflow() |> 
  add_recipe(ranger_recipe)  |>  
  add_model(ranger_spec) 

set.seed(93186)
ranger_tune =
  tune_grid(ranger_workflow, 
            resamples = rf_folds, 
            control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE))
```

I am, relatively, new to R and tidymodels.  Please, point out my mistakes and I am open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you use `cbind` it will convert to a matrix with only one class. This means that your y1 will still be a numeric variable. You check it with `class` but this is the y1 still before `cbind`, so you should convert it back to a factor like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(themis)
library(dplyr)
library(vip)
library(forcats)

set.seed(987)
n = 1500

#simulated data
v1 = sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = TRUE)
v2 = round(runif(n, 18, 80))
v3 = sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = TRUE)
v4 = sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = TRUE)
v5 = sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = TRUE)
v6 = rbinom(n = n, size = 1, prob = .50)

xb = -9 + 3.5*v1 + 0.2*v2 + 0*v3 + 0*v4 +0*v5 + 0*v6  
p = 1/(1 + exp(-xb))

y1 = rbinom(n = n, size = 1, prob = p)

y1 = 
  dplyr::recode_factor(y1, `1` = "yes", `2` =  "no")
#> Warning: Unreplaced values treated as NA as `.x` is not compatible.
#> Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply `.default`.

dat_set = as.data.frame(cbind(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, y1))

# check type
str(dat_set)
#> 'data.frame':    1500 obs. of  7 variables:
#>  $ v1: num  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ v2: num  53 23 25 70 68 78 62 48 46 56 ...
#>  $ v3: num  1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
#>  $ v4: num  1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 ...
#>  $ v5: num  1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 ...
#>  $ v6: num  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 ...
#>  $ y1: num  1 NA NA 1 1 1 1 NA NA 1 ...

# Convert to factor
dat_set$y1 <- as.factor(dat_set$y1)

dat_set |> 
  count(y1)
#>     y1    n
#> 1    1 1015
#> 2 <NA>  485

class(y1)
#> [1] "factor"

#splitting into training and testing data
set.seed(123)
rf_split = initial_split(dat_set, strata = y1)
rf_train = training(rf_split)
rf_test = testing(rf_split)

#developing the model
set.seed(234)
rf_folds = vfold_cv(rf_train, strata = y1)

ranger_recipe = 
  recipe(formula = y1 ~ ., data = rf_train)

ranger_spec = 
  rand_forest(mtry = tune(), min_n = tune(), trees = 1000)  |>  
  set_mode("classification")  |>  
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity") 

ranger_workflow = 
  workflow() |> 
  add_recipe(ranger_recipe)  |>  
  add_model(ranger_spec) 

set.seed(93186)
ranger_tune =
  tune_grid(ranger_workflow, 
            resamples = rf_folds, 
            control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE))
#> i Creating pre-processing data to finalize unknown parameter: mtry
#> x Fold01: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold01: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold01: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold01: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold01: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold01: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold01: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold01: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold01: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold01: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold02: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold02: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold02: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold02: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold02: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold02: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold02: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold02: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold02: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold02: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold03: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold03: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold03: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold03: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold03: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold03: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold03: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold03: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold03: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold03: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold04: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold04: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold04: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold04: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold04: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold04: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold04: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold04: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold04: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold04: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold05: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold05: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold05: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold05: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold05: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold05: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold05: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold05: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold05: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold05: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold06: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold06: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold06: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold06: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold06: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold06: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold06: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold06: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold06: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold06: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold07: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold07: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold07: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold07: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold07: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold07: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold07: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold07: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold07: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold07: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold08: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold08: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold08: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold08: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold08: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold08: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold08: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold08: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold08: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold08: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold09: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold09: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold09: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold09: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold09: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold09: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold09: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold09: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold09: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold09: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold10: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold10: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold10: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold10: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold10: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold10: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold10: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold10: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold10: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> x Fold10: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10: Error: Missing data in dependent variable.
#> Warning: All models failed. Run `show_notes(.Last.tune.result)` for more
#> information.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is great!  I see the issue now.  Thank you